# Bluetooth is not reading every characteristic

Tags: android, bluetooth

I've got problem with Bluetooth in my app. I've got lots of characteristics and can read only 2. When I try to read more I'm not getting any callback. I read that I should create queue but don't know how to do it. Any help, please ?

Here's my characteristics :

```
 private void registerParametersCharacteristics(List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> characteristics) {
        for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic : characteristics) {
            UUID characteristicUuid = characteristic.getUuid();
            if (Characteristics.EON_PARAMS_EDDYSTONE_UID_CHAR.equals(characteristicUuid)) {
                euidCharacteristic = characteristic;
                Log.e(TAG, "registerParametersCharacteristics: EUID" );
            }
            else if (Characteristics.EON_PARAMS_EDDYSTONE_EID_CHAR.equals(characteristicUuid)) {
                eeidCharacteristic = characteristic;}
            else if (Characteristics.EON_PARAMS_EDDYSTONE_URL_CHAR.equals(characteristicUuid)) {
                eurlCharacteristic = characteristic;}
            else if (Characteristics.EON_PARAMS_EDDYSTONE_TLM_CHAR.equals(characteristicUuid)) {
                etlmCharacteristic = characteristic;}
            else if (Characteristics.EON_PARAMS_EDDYSTONE_UID_UUID.equals(characteristicUuid)) {
                eUidUUidCharacteristic = characteristic;}
            else if (Characteristics.EON_PARAMS_EDDYSTONE_URL_UUID.equals(characteristicUuid)) {
                eUrlUuidCharacteristic = characteristic;
                Log.e(TAG, "registerParametersCharacteristics: EurlUUID" );
            }
            else if (Characteristics.MINOR_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID.equals(characteristicUuid)) {
                minorCharacteristic = characteristic;}
            else if (Characteristics.MAJOR_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID.equals(characteristicUuid)) {
                majorCharacteristic = characteristic;
            }
            else if (Characteristics.UUID_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID.equals(characteristicUuid)){
                uuidCharacteristic = characteristic;
            }
            else if (Characteristics.INTERVAL_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID.equals(characteristicUuid)) {
                intervalCharacteristic = characteristic;
            }
            else if (Characteristics.TX_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID.equals(characteristicUuid)) {
                txCharacteristic = characteristic;
            }
            else if (Characteristics.BATTERY_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID.equals(characteristicUuid)) {
                batteryCharacteristic = characteristic;
                Log.e(TAG, "registerParametersCharacteristics: BAT" );
            }
            Log.e(TAG, "registerParametersCharacteristics: " + characteristic.getUuid().toString() );
        }
    }
```

and this is my onServicediscovered method :

```
@Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status);
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                List<BluetoothGattService> services = gatt.getServices();
                for (BluetoothGattService service : services) {
                    registerService(service);
                    Log.e(TAG, "onServicesDiscovered: " + service.getUuid().toString() );
                }
                callback.connectedStateChanged(true);
            } else
                disconnect();
        }
        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
            super.onCharacteristicRead(gatt, characteristic, status);
            characteristicValueRead(characteristic);
            BluetoothCommunicationManager.getInstance().processNext();
        }
```

I lost two days to write this queue and can't do it. Thanks in advance for every help.

Answer (score 0):

you should use 'command' design pattern. Basically, you'll have abstract class or interface with single 'execute(..)' method. You will create classes, extending that 'Command' class, but every implementation will do its own work.
Then you can create 'ArrayList', add all your tasks into it and process those tasks in 'for' loop like:

```
for (Command c : commands){
 c.execute(..);
{
```

Comment: Alex any example please?